# How to use comma separated columns in CASE WHEN Statement?

Tags: sql-server, where

I am trying to add below `CASE WHEN` Statement in SQL `WHERE` Clause, But SQL Server not allowing me to do so. All column used are of same `Data Types` but still its giving me error, Can anyone please check and advice why its not working?

```
WHERE supplierAccountDetail.SupplierMasterID IN (
        CASE 
            WHEN @SupplierMasterID IS NOT NULL
                THEN @SupplierMasterID
            ELSE (sales.ParentSupplierMasterID
                ,sales.DivisionSupplierMasterID) //Error - Syntax Error
            END
        )
```

Comment: `WHERE ( @SupplierMasterID IS NOT NULL AND supplierAccountDetail.SupplierMasterID IN ( @SupplierMasterID ) )
      OR ( @SupplierMasterID IS NULL AND supplierAccountDetail.SupplierMasterID IN (sales.ParentSupplierMasterID, sales.DivisionSupplierMasterID) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the `CASE WHEN` statements then you have to specify a new `CASE WHEN` statement per column / value in the `IN()` statement.

Example:

```
    WHERE supplierAccountDetail.SupplierMasterID 
    IN(
    CASE 
    WHEN @SupplierMasterID IS NOT NULL
    THEN @SupplierMasterID
    ELSE sales.ParentSupplierMasterID END
    ,
    CASE 
    WHEN @SupplierMasterID IS NOT NULL
    THEN @SupplierMasterID
    ELSE sales.DivisionSupplierMasterID END);
```

This does mean that you will compare your column to the variable twice.

Alternatively you could change the query to what [Akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina) mentioned in the comments:

```
WHERE (supplierAccountDetail.SupplierMasterID  = @SupplierMasterID AND  @SupplierMasterID IS NOT NULL)
OR 
(
@SupplierMasterID IS NULL 
AND
(
 supplierAccountDetail.SupplierMasterID IN(sales.ParentSupplierMasterID,sales.DivisionSupplierMasterID) )
);
```

Comment: An alternative for CASE: `IN (COALESCE(@SupplierMasterID, sales.ParentSupplierMasterID), COALESCE(@SupplierMasterID, sales.DivisionSupplierMasterID))`